# Capturing Traffic from Specific Application (EXE) Only

Tags: wireshark

Is it possible to filter a specific application (.exe) in Wireshark and listen only to the traffic of that running process? If yes, how or what's the filter syntax?

I can't seem to find any search results that answers my question. Not sure if I'm wording it incorrectly.

Thanks!

Comment: Capturing traffic is not a security specific question, i.e. off-topic. Apart from that similar questions and answers are [easy to find using a search engine](https://www.google.com/search?q=wireshark+capture+filter+process). See [Wireshark, monitor certain process/task or prevent ordinary packets be monitored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61042972/), [How to capture network traffic by process name in mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561791/), [Sniffing TCP traffic for specific process using Wireshark](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1970/), ...

Comment: @Steffen: Sorry about that, but thank you for still providing an answer. I'll have a look. Cheers